# Icon size of imageorient selection

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I have extended the imageorient selection with some additional options:

TSconfig:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.types.textmedia.addItems{
  101 = XL Image
  101.icon = img_xl
  # …
}
```

The new icons are already registered via the [Icon API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Icon/Index.html) in a sitepackage.

ext:sitepackage/Configuration/Icons.php

```
<?php
   return [
        'img_xl' => [
            'provider' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
            'source' => 'EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/img_xl.svg',
        ],
        'mybitmapicon' => [
            'provider' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\BitmapIconProvider::class,
            'source' => 'EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/test.png',
        ],
   ];
```

It looks like this:

[image]

They are displayed with 16x16 pixels, no matter how big they actually are (I tried it with svg and png of different sizes).
Since some are a bit more complex than the standard icons, I would like to make them larger.
Whether the standard icons scale is not important.

**Is there any way to influence the output size?**

In the TCA Reference [it looks like this could be possible](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select/Single/Examples.html#select-foreign-rows-with-icons), since the example has larger images shown. Probably the TCA would need to be modified via `ext:sitepackage/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`, but it's unclear to me how exactly.

Comment: Can you add your icon registration code?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala I have just added the registration code.

Comment: I ran into the same necessity and just added an additional backend CSS file to my sitepackage as that was the most simple way to make it work in all TYPO3 versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are rendered in `SelectIcons::render()` ([Code](https://api.typo3.org/master/_select_icons_8php_source.html#l00034)) using the `FormEngineUtility::getIconHtml()`-function ([Code](https://api.typo3.org/master/_form_engine_utility_8php_source.html#l00121)).

The rendering depends on the icons declaration:

### Icons as file-reference

The Icons are rendered without width/height attributes in HTML. So, it should be possible to use them sized as you want.

### Sprite Icons name

The icons are finally rendered by calling `IconFactory::createIcon` ([Code](https://api.typo3.org/master/_icon_factory_8php_source.html#l00491)) with a fixed size of 16px (`Icon::SIZE_SMALL= 'small' // 16`).
On a simple way via configuration, another size won't (currently) be possible.